# Swift - Downcasting an array of protocols to type crashes with unsafeBitCast Fatal Error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to cast a 'filtered' array of a protocol type

I have a series of structs (Assessment, Level and Gate) that conform to several different Protocols - Stageable, Repeatable and Testable:

```
protocol Stageable
{
    var index : Int { get }
    var steps : [Step] { get }
}

protocol Testable
{
    var threshold : Float { get }
}

protocol Repeatable
{
    var sessions: Int { get }
}

struct Gate : Stageable, Testable, Repeatable
{
    private(set) var index : Int
    private(set) var steps : [Step]

    private(set) var threshold : Float

    private(set) var sessions : Int
}

struct Assessment : Stageable, Testable
{
    private(set) var index : Int
    private(set) var steps : [Step]

    private(set) var threshold : Float
}

struct Level : Stageable, Repeatable
{
    private(set) var index : Int
    private(set) var steps : [Step]

    private(set) var sessions : Int
}
```

Step is another struct. There are no classes being used.

These structs are populated just before being added to an array. 
An array takes the form usually of [Assessment, Gate, Level, Level]. All the structs data is populated from an XML file.

In some instances I only want to review the 'Levels' in the array, so I do:

```
// stages = [Assessment, Gate, Level, Level, ...]
let levels = stages.filter{ $0 is Level }
```

If I query this, it looks fine e.g. levels.count is what I expect.
However, if I now want to cast the array to [Level] it crashes with the following error:

```
fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes
```

Is this because I'm casting from a protocol to a struct type? I also feel like I've missed the key benefits of Protocols here and there must be a better way to do this.

Currently using Xcode 7 beta 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting arrays of structs is problematic because structs are value types. That means each element of an array of structs takes up the size of the struct in memory. This is different for arrays of standard objects because these are passed by reference. Each element in an array of objects is a reference (a pointer to a specific memory area).

To demonstrate this, consider the following

```
class ABC {
    private var i = 0
    private var j = 1
    private var k = 2
}

print(sizeof(UIViewController))
print(sizeof(UIImage))
print(sizeof(NSObject))
print(sizeof(ABC))
```

Each of the `print` statements outputs `8` on my platform which is the size of a memory address (which is obviously different from the amount of memory occupied by instances of this class).

On the other hand, when I take the code from your question and do

```
print(sizeof(Stageable))
print(sizeof(Level))
```

I get `40` and `24` respectively which are the actual sizes of instances of these structs in memory. That means an array of type `[Stageable]` consists of chunks of 40 byte elements whereas an array of type `[Level]` consists of chunks of 24 byte elements. As a result you cannot cast between such array types because that would require the array's memory to be rewritten.

As an alternative, you can use the `map` method to force type conversion:

```
let levels = stages.filter({ $0 is Level }).map({ $0 as! Level })
```

The above can also be simplified by leveraging the `flatMap` method:

```
let levels = stages.flatMap({ $0 as? Level })
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation and demonstrating a good use case for FlatMap.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you execute this code:

```
let levels = stages.filter{ $0 is Level }
```

your `levels` type become `[Stageable]`. Now, to convert `[Stageable]` to `[Level]` you can use this code:

```
var l = levels.map{ $0 as! Level }
```